# Are contract calls asynchronous in web3.js?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, web3js

Suppose we have a contract:

```
contract C {

    uint256 a;
    uint256 b;

    function setA(uint256 aval) {
        a = aval;
    }

    function setB(uint256 bval) {
        b = bval;
    }

    function getA() constant returns (uint256) { 
        return a;
    }

    function getB() constant returns (uint256) {
        return b;
    }
}
```

and we try to set values, get them and store them into an array using **web3.js**:

```
var ABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"bval","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setB","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getB","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getA","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"aval","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setA","outputs":[],"type":"function"}];
var contractAddress = "0x11111222222222222222";
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, ABI);
var numbers = [];

// Set the values
contract.call().setA(100);
contract.call().setB(200);

// Get them and add them to the array
var a = contract.call().getA();
numbers.push(a);
var b = contract.call().getB();
numbers.push(b);
```

Can **b** be added to the array before **a**? I know that **web** is asynchronous for most methods but does this apply to contract method invocation as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are both synchronous and asynchronous versions of:

`myContractInstance.myMethod.call(param1 [, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, defaultBlock] [, callback]);`

as documented in https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods

Using the synchronous version:

```
var a = contract.getA.call();
numbers.push(a);
var b = contract.getB.call();
numbers.push(b);
```

`b` will always be in the array after `a`.

---

To use the asynchronous version, you pass a callback, like:

```
var a = contract.getA.call(function(error, value) {
});
```

The order of the array will depend on what's done in the callback/s.

---

Note that `sendTransaction` should be used for setting the values and this won't work:

```
// Set the values
contract.call().setA(100);
contract.call().setB(200);
```

You need to use:

`contract.setA.sendTransaction(100, callback);` and all the other code needs to be inside the `callback`, because `sendTransaction` is only asynchronous.  Furthermore, the `callback` of `sendTransaction` will only return a transaction hash and you need to poll until [getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) is not `null` to know that the transaction has been mined and the value of `a` has been set.

Comment: So the syntax for synchronously invoked methods is <contract_name>.<method_name>().call(); ? and for the async you also pass the callback function as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for also editing my syntax mistakes :)  Your edits are good, and yes for "async you also pass the callback function as an argument".